# How to stop these elements from moving together?

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/gq6En/62/

this fiddle allows you to drag and drop little boxes into the white or yellow bigger boxes. But if you drag the orange box into the white box, and then, for example, drag the blue box into the yellow box, the orange box will move (out of the white box) at the same time that the blue box is moving. i.e. the little boxes are somehow linked together after they have been dragged or dropped.

How can I move the blue box into the white without moving the orange box out of the white box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unselect jQuery Lint and try again: http://jsfiddle.net/gq6En/65/